# Tacx Flow loud noise, HELP!

Tags: repair

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me. I am a complete novice and know nothing about any of this so I apologise. I recently purchased a Tacx Flux secondhand and have attached my bike to it and its making this awful noise! Does anyone know what the problem can be, or how to fix it, or is the trainer broken? Any suggestions or thoughts are welcomed! Thanks guys

It can be seen/heard here

Comment: Sounds broken. I do not think you can do anything, send it back.

Comment: Trainers are not my area, but that sounds dreadful.  Are you positive there's no brake mechanism activated?  Or perhaps some packing peanuts in the works somewhere?  Ask the seller if that's as they shipped it, you may have recourse against the carrier if it was damaged in transit.

Comment: This looks like one of those from the first generation where they had massive problems with the belt that drives the flywheel.

Comment: You can send your video link to support@tacx.com and they will advise. If it’s an older unit the chances of a repair or exchange are slim, even more so if OP bought second hand / used.